Creating a connected graph constrained to a 2d grid
I would like to create a function making random connected and acyclic graphs which are constrained to having vertices points on a grid and edges going horizontally and vertically between them, as in this picture for example (ignore the two different colours):

I tried to do this modifying some existence code for self-avoiding walks on a grid:
from random import choice
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8-darkgrid')
print(plt.style.available)

def tree(n):
    x, y = 0, 0
    path = [(x, y)]
    for i in range(n):
        thx,thy = choice(path[j] for j in range(len(path)))
        # pick the closest point but it must complete without crossing itself
        x, y = choice([(thx+1, thy), (thx-1, thy), (thx, thy+1), (thx, thy-1)])
        if (x, y) in path:
            return path
        path.append((x, y))
    return path

# show plot
def show_path(path):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    # draw points
    plt.scatter(*zip(*path), s=5, c='k')
    # draw lines in red
    plt.plot(*zip(*path), c='r')
    plt.show()

path = tree(100000)
show_path(path)

but this gives me the error "object of type 'generator' has no len()". If someone could tell me how to fix this error, or help me write entirely different code which accomplishes the same goal I'd appreciate it.

For that particular error, add the [] brackets for the list comprehension. thx,thy = choice([path[j] for j in range(len(path))]) - not sure what’s needed thereafter.

The error is probably in this line:
thx,thy = choice(path[j] for j in range(len(path)))

The choice function must know how many elements there are to choose amongst. Hence, you cannot use a generator as argument. You must use a list:
thx,thy = choice([path[j] for j in range(len(path))])

or much simpler
thx,thy = choice(path)

Also,

your path variable is kind of a misnomer, because it actually stores the points (nodes), not the edges of the graph
your algorithm will terminate prematurely once it detects a loop (use continue instead of return)
Since you only store points, not edges, you won't be able to tell whether adjacent points are connected or disconnected (parallel-running branches). You should return edges: ((thx, thy), (x, y)) in addition or instead of the points.
the larger your graph gets, the more time will be wasted by testing points that have no available connections anymore. Can be solved by maintaining a subset of "border" points, where you remove points once they have no more possible connections, and choosing branch points from that set.

Beyond that, what you want to achieve is the well-known "Maze generation" problem. You can find some algorithms and further reading on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm
Your approach resembles the "Iterative randomized Prim's algorithm".
